# Assign program to NUM key

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, numlock

I'm looking for a native way to assign keyboard shortcuts to the launch programs on Windows 7 without having to install a third-party tool like AutoHotKey and get to grips with its scripting language.

The easiest method to do this is would be to right-click on Properties of the program in the Start Menu (or another shortcut located on the Desktop), click the Shortcut tab and type a shortcut into the designated field. However, this method seems to force you to use a combination of Ctrl + Shift/Alt along with the target key. I'm hoping to find a way to do this so that just clicking NUM KEY 1 for example, would launch a program, without using any other keys. It's short and sweet, and works since I have no other use for the NUMPAD when num lock is off.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the lack of answers I recieved, it would seem there is currently no native way to do this, so I decided to take the plunge and go with AutoHotKey. AutoHotKey is a 6.3MB download and is relatively easy to get started with, so the tradeoff is not too significant.

I did the following in order to get the launch-on-one-key functionality I wanted.

**[Install the program](https://autohotkey.com/). Once it's installed, right-click on the Desktop, click New, and then click AutoHotkey Script to create a script file.**

The below script took me all of about 15 mins to write. **Copy-paste it into the newly-created script file, making sure it's below any content already inside of it.**

```
NumpadLeft::
Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Return

NumpadUp::
Run C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe
Return

NumpadPgUp::
Run B:\Users\Hashim\AppData\Local\Wunderlist\Wunderlist.exe
Return

NumpadClear::
Run C:\Program Files\CyberGhost 6\CyberGhost.exeReturn

NumpadRight::
Run C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS4 (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe
Return

NumpadDown::
Run C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Return
```

Note that the first line of each block of code in the above script is a keycode that represents a key on your keyboard, while the second is a Run command followed by the path of the application that you want that key to launch.

**Replace the keycode in the script with the keycode of the key that you want to use, and then replace the path with a path to the application that you want that key to launch.**

A full list of mappable keys can be found here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm.

**Once done, save the script, and double-click on it to run it for the first time. If everything went well, you should now be able to launch your programs using the keys you assigned.**

AHK scripts usually need to be run manually like this first in order to be activated - this means that you'd usually need to click on a script to run it before it'll work. To avoid this, you simply need to ensure that your script is run on startup.

**On Windows 7, the easiest way of accomplishing this is by placing the completed script in the Startup folder:**

`USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

You should now be able to run your programs from the keyboard the moment Windows loads, without having to run the script first.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a desktop shortcut of the executable, go to its Properties->Shortcut tab, and you will see a "Shortcut Key" field. Click it and press a key-combination, and "Apply"
- Another way of achieving this is to pin the shortcut to the task bar, and simply press Windows Key + *n*, where *n* is the number of icons from the "Start" menu button.
  e.g. If I have pinned shortcuts to the taskbar, in the same order:
  [image: Windows Taskbar]
  To launch Google Chrome, I can simple press Win key + 1.
  To launch File Explorer, I can press Win key + 3.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to add some more information. I'm aware of the first method, but I'd like to get something like it that would enable me to launch a program by pressing just one NUMPAD key.

Comment: @Hashim that's currently not available in Windows, but if you aren't comfortable with AutoHotKey, there are other 3rd party utilities with a GUI. Read this [page](http://lifehacker.com/5886866/the-best-global-hotkey-manager-for-windows) to learn more...